# How to copy or TypeCast a javascript object to a variable with the base class

Tags: javascript, dojo, type-conversion

I have a Javascript Object (It's a dojo/stateful object), that I created from a data structure. I want to convert that stateful object back to a standard hash object.

```
a = {test: "a test"};
b = new stateful(a);
new_a = new object(a);
```

The reason for this is because I have a function that needs to be passed an object with the base object class. Passing it a stateful object doesn't work, even though the data structures are the same.

I've found that doing a

```
new_a = b;
new_a.__proto__ = new_a.__proto__.__proto__
```

will do what I want in the version of Chrome I'm using, but I'm guessing this is a really bad way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could create watches for each property on the original object.  This will keep the original object in sync with changes to the stateful object.

This example extends the `dojo/Stateful` object to keep the original and adds the watches to update the original object.

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/YJHtH/